# Subsetting in R based on shared characters in a row name

Tags: r, subset

this is a largely primitive question but I can't seem to figure it out:

I have a list of SNPS with a corresponding `cos` and `Pvalue` in R as a data frame called `snps`:

```
 RS         cos      Pval
1 rs31192577 -0.15583497 0.2241433
2 rs32166183 -0.12573989 0.2934898
3 rs30543887 -0.07852091 0.5141007
4  rs6365082  0.55173702 0.1736945
5 rs46229295 -0.10897376 0.3687622
6 rs45964436         NaN 1.0000000
```

however, some of the RS are named `no_rs1`, `no_rs2` in case there is no SNP name for that location.

I just want to filter out the ones with the "rs" in their name and the corresponding `cos` and `Pvalue` into `snps2` data frame (and thereby get rid of the no_rs ones), but for the love of me I can't seem to get the syntax right:

```
snps2<-subset(snps, RS=="rs$")

snps2<-subset(snps, RS=="rs*")
```

doesn't do the trick...

I work with subset commonly using numerical limitations, i.e.

```
snps2<-subset(snps, Pval<0.05)
```

does precisely what I need it do - gives me only those rows in which the Pval is below 0.05, but I can't get the rs filtering right.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
df[grepl("^rs", df$RS),]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need to use is `grepl`. The trick is that `subset` (or the `[` operator) both work with logical vectors. The `subset` environment just makes it easier to refer to columns of the data.frame, from there anything that creates a logical vector (of the correct length) will work.

```
snps <- structure(list(RS = c("rs31192577", "rs32166183", "rs30543887", 
"no_rs6365082", "rs46229295", "no_rs45964436"), cos = c(-0.15583497, 
-0.12573989, -0.07852091, 0.55173702, -0.10897376, NaN), Pval = c(0.2241433, 
0.2934898, 0.5141007, 0.1736945, 0.3687622, 1)), .Names = c("RS", 
"cos", "Pval"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Since your data only has `rs*` rows, I'll change a couple for effect:

```
snps$RS[c(4,6)] <- paste0('no_', snps$RS[c(4,6)])
snps
##              RS         cos      Pval
## 1    rs31192577 -0.15583497 0.2241433
## 2    rs32166183 -0.12573989 0.2934898
## 3    rs30543887 -0.07852091 0.5141007
## 4  no_rs6365082  0.55173702 0.1736945
## 5    rs46229295 -0.10897376 0.3687622
## 6 no_rs45964436         NaN 1.0000000
```

The subsetting, whether you use the `[` operator or `subset`, can use `grepl`:

```
subset(snps, grepl('^no_', RS))
##              RS      cos      Pval
## 4  no_rs6365082 0.551737 0.1736945
## 6 no_rs45964436      NaN 1.0000000
## similarly: snps[grepl('^no_', snps$RS),]

subset(snps, !grepl('^no_', RS))
##           RS         cos      Pval
## 1 rs31192577 -0.15583497 0.2241433
## 2 rs32166183 -0.12573989 0.2934898
## 3 rs30543887 -0.07852091 0.5141007
## 5 rs46229295 -0.10897376 0.3687622
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison operator `==` literally compares the `snps$RS` variable to the strings you specified and does not use the special characters. You can use regular expressions to solve your problem using the  `grepl` function. The following should work:

```
snps2 <- snps[grepl("^rs", snps$RS), ]
```

or if you prefer to use the `subset` function:

```
snps2 <- subset(snps, grepl("^rs",snps$RS))
```